# difference between using ip address and domain name

Tags: java, ip

What is the difference between using ip address and domain name in 
    java web application?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov if DNS is the problem why i can able to send mail first time?

Comment: because you are using IP address directly. DNS performs conversion from domain name to IP, and if it fails, the application won't be able to connect

Comment: It's not entirely clearly what the situation is.  Are you sending e-mail twice with a domain name and it's failing on the second attempt?  The way your question is currently phrased it sounds like you're sending it using an IP address and then with a domain name.

Comment: yes that is the problem i have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is an IP address and Domain Name:**

**IP address:** IP address is a way of giving address to every computer over the Network.

**Domain Name:** Domain Name are used instead of IP address as its easier to remember Names rather than Numbers for humans.

**Whats the problem when IP addresses are used in Applications:**

**-** IP can change over time due to various reason, sometimes due to technical and sometimes due to political reason within or outside the organization.

**-** Now if the application is bound with Domain name, then there is **No need** to change the anything into the application code, else when we use IP address, its sort of Hard Coding..which is a bad practice.

**Your Problem:**

I think there is a mapping problem between the IP address and Domain Name you are using. You can always use `Ping` as one of the reliable tool to check this.

**First ping using the Domain name :**

`ping www.google.com`

**Then ping using the IP address:**

`ping 173.194.38.134`

Comment: if there is a mapping problem exist remaining functionality is working properly.is there any reason?

Comment: If you code is working as expected using the IP address then i think there is only a mapping problem

Comment: when i use domain name also remaining functionality is same only one scenario is not working

Comment: first i need to invite a friend into our application through invitation.Then he will enter into our site by using a verification link.Then he will fill the registration fields to complete his profile.Then we will send again a verification link to him and we will do some database updates along with sending mail.Second time operations are not working

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this code in your app, and if it does not print the same IP address as supposed, problem with DNS.

```
InetAddress sambapAddress = java.net.InetAddress.getByName("www.sambap.com");
String address = sambapAddress.getHostAddress();
System.out.println(address);
```

Comment: that means you are saying when i used ip address and when i use domain name

Comment: @sambapenugonda, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: i mean in our application there is a issue exist when i use domain name.That is not exist when i use ip address.But the remaining functionality is same.

Comment: @sambapenugonda, so what is the question? what IP you are using and what the code above prints you, is it same?

Comment: actually i got the ip address from the net by typing my domain name

Comment: and we also used same ip address in different places.ip address is correct.

Comment: @sambapenugonda, I will ask again the same question. Is the IP you use explicitly, same from what got printed by code by me?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22429/discussion-between-samba-penugonda-and-nikolay-kuznetsov)